# Repo upload denied for project

Tags: git, repository

I am facing below error when I do a “repo upload”. Can anyone provide inputs on what could be the problem?

```
fatal: Upload denied for project 'platform/external/data_supp_8'
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error :

```
Upload denied for project 'platform/external/data_supp_8'
```

You are an administrator doesn't mean you have push permission to a project.  It sounds like you lost your READ +2 permission here.  Shouldn't have happened as a result of using
create-project.  Check your group memberships in `Settings > Groups`,  are they still what you expect them to be?  Check your access controls on project "news", are they granting you READ +2 somewhere?  Check your Git configuration, are you sure you are logging in as yourself
and not as the role account?